# Regex for everything before last forward or backward slash

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will find everything in a string up to and including the last \ or /.

For example, c:\directory\file.txt should result in c:\directory\

Answer (score 60):

Try this: [(Rubular)](http://www.rubular.com/r/qMjioXRiOG)

```
/^(.*[\\\/])/
```

Explanation:

```
^      Start of line/string
(      Start capturing group
.*     Match any character greedily
[\\\/] Match a backslash or a forward slash
)      End the capturing group
```

The matched slash will be the last one because of the greediness of the `.*`.

If your language supports (or requires) it, you may wish to use a different delimiter than `/` for the regular expression so that you don't have to escape the forward-slash.

Also, if you are parsing file paths you will probably find that your language already has a library that does this. This would be better than using a regular expression.

Comment: +1 for **...you will probably find that your language already has a library that does this...**

Comment: Yep. In R, it's basename()

Answer (score 4):

`^(.*[\\\/])[^\\\/]*$`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **sed** for example, you could do this to output everything before the last slash:

```
echo "/home/me/documents/morestuff/before_last/last" | sed s:/[^/]*$::
```

It will output:

```
/home/me/documents/morestuff/before_last
```